# how to pass complex string to pymongo for query by python?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I need to filter the webserver requests and setting a query for pymongo, its not so simple as I need to have "and", or "or" functionality for multiple fields.

I have filtered the get request, got the parameters, built the string to be passed to db..find. But it throws error. I have identified the error as because I am forming a string like this to passed to the function, now as its a string and not actually a dict, its throwing an error. What is the right way of doing it?

Actually, I have to get something like: {$and:[{Title:{"$regex":"Hong Kong"}},{Url:{"$regex":"hong"}}]}{'_id':0, 'Body':0}

The get request I am sending is: http://127.0.0.1:5000/getRequest?Title="Hong Kong protest"&Url="hong" Now the below thing gives the exact required string, but it throws an error as its not supposed to be string. Please help.

```
@app.route('/getRequest', methods=['GET'])
def request():
    global connection
    args = request.args
    if len(args) > 1:
        search_str = ""
        for key, val in args.items():
            search_str += '{'+key+':{"$regex":'+str(val)+'}},'
        search_str = search_str[:-1]
        display_dict={'id':0, 'Body':0}
        final_search_str = "{$and:["+search_str+"]},{'_id':0, 'Body':0}"
    #return(final_search_str)
    # query_str = request.args.get('query_string')
    db = connection['test']
    collection = db['collect1']

    output = []
    for s in collection.find(final_search_str):
            output.append({'Title' : s['Title'], 'Url' : s['Url']})
```

It should be dict which should be passed to the function. Any better way to do this complex query via pymongo?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using re and bson.regex.Regex module.
http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/regex.html

```
import re 
from bson.regex import Regex
query = {}
for key, val in args.items():
    pattern = re.compile(val) 
    regex = Regex.from_native(regex)
    query[key] = regex

for s in collection.find(query):
            output.append({'Title' : s['Title'], 'Url' : s['Url']})
```